# How does this integration make sense?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I simply don't understand how integration can lead from:
$ds^2 = a^2(t) \frac{dr^2}{1 - kr^2}$

to
$s(r) = \frac{\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{k}r)}{\sqrt{k}}$

I appologize, I've never been quite capable of calculus, but I'd love an explanation!

Comment: Is this a Mathematica related question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearrange the notation to get the following.
$$
\left(\frac{ds}{dr}\right)^2 = \frac{a^2(t)}{1-kr^2}\Rightarrow  ds = \pm a(t) \frac{dr}{\sqrt{1-kr^2}} \\
\int ds = \pm a(t) \int \frac{dr}{\sqrt{1-kr^2}} = \pm \frac{a(t)}{\sqrt{k}} \int \frac{dr}{\sqrt{1-kr^2}} \frac{d(\sqrt{k}r)}{dr}= \pm \frac{a(t)}{\sqrt{k}} \int \frac{d(\sqrt{k}r)}{\sqrt{1-kr^2}}\\
s(r) = \pm a(t) \frac{\sin^{-1} (\sqrt{k} r)}{\sqrt{k}} +C
$$
If $a(t) = 1$ and we take the positive solution and the constant of integration is zero then this is indeed possible.